# Show variable value in list?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<script>
  var a=8;
  var b=5;
  var c=8;
  var d=9;
</script>

<select size="5">
    <option value="1">"a" seats remaining</option>
    <option value="2">"b" seats remaining</option>
    <option value="3">"c" seats remaining</option>
    <option value="4">"d" seats remaining</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

In the list, instead of a,b,c,d, can i show the values of the variables like 8,5,8,9?

Comment: Have already seen this question... you really made a new account? You are mixing html with javascript/php

Comment: no, i used my fb account... i'hav been struggling with this... where did you see PHP in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your options an ID for easy access:

```
<select size="5">
    <option id="a" value="1"></option>
    <option id="b" value="2"></option>
    <option id="c" value="3"></option>
    <option id="d" value="4"></option>
</select>
```

Then you can simple do something like

```
var a=8;
var b=5;
var c=8;
var d=9;

document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = a + ' seats remaining';
document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = b + ' seats remaining';
document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = c + ' seats remaining';
document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = d + ' seats remaining';
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ayp28/

Answer (score 0):

Try this with using jQuery if you want to replace.

```
$("select > option").each(function() {
    var array = {"a":"8", "b":"5", "c":"8", "d":"9"};
    for (var val in array)
        this.text = this.text.split('"' + val + '"').join('"' + array[val] + '"');
});
```